# Is double tapping or bursting more effective?

Tags: counter-strike-source

Since the Orange Box update and the updates after that, CSS has changed a lot with regards to hitboxes and recoil.  Before the updates I played pro skill and most people would just burst and some would do the double tap (burst), which is tapping twice to get a smaller recoil than using the normal burst which uses 3 or 4 bullets.  However, I started playing again and I noticed that the better players are using the double tap now.

Is it better to double tap?

Comment: I usually Spray And Pray, which is probably why I don't do all that well.

Comment: xD i used to be an awper in the team however after the hitbox changes i can't flickshot that proper anymore :( so going to train my rifle skills again and just play as all rounder :D however now it would be nice if i started learning with the proper method double tapping is working good however would like to know why people changed it since everyone used to burst. however i also started with spray and pray so just keep learning and u will end up as a very good player :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends,

on how your style is...

I mean its a classic FPS which even these days people play it a lot even with the "hitboxes"

Double tap will bring more accuracy to your hits and most of the bullets will end at the target

Burst on the other hand need more movement on the mouse when you burst you need to move it to the opposite direction of the gun that burst.. :)

So close target i would say burst

far targets double tap!

Comment: well i do know the recoil patterns of the game however i'm curious why this is changed after the updates since now the most are using the double tap and they used to burst (i'm using double tap atm and it does work perfect (close and far range))

Comment: Maybe they wanted to be more accurate because before wasn't so accurate ? or with the hitboxes thing is better to be double tap than burst really this a question that we must ask it directly to the devs and get "inside" answer!

Comment: @ronnie Feel free to dress up your comment and answer your own question. That is encouraged here to share your knowledge with others.

Comment: and for me last comment will be... what fit better to the person that plays... every one have there on style... system configs.. so nothing is standard..!